# maven doesn't see a newest archetype

Tags: maven

There is a newest version 4.1.3 of this archetype:
[jbehave-simple-archetype](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbehave/jbehave-simple-archetype/4.1.3)

published on https://mvnrepository.com site:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbehave/jbehave-simple-archetype -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbehave-simple-archetype</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

However neither Eclipse nor mvn command don't see this version, for example if I run this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jbehave ^
-DarchetypeArtifactId=jbehave-simple-archetype ^
-DarchetypeVersion=4.1.3 ^
-DgroupId=com.company -DartifactId=someproject -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.company.project
```

Maven uses 4.1.2 version, this is a message I've got which says that version 4.1.2 is used but not 4.1.3:

```
[INFO] Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [org.jbehave:jbehave-simple-archetype:4.1.2] found in catalog remote
```

How can I generate a project using the newest version of this archetype ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest seems not to be in Maven Central repository.

I managed to get `4.1.3` by adding this to my pom

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>a</id>
    <url>https://mvnrepository.com</url>
    <releases>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
 </repository>
</repositories>
```

**Update**

weird but now it seems to work without this added `repositories` section. I removed it and deleted all `jbehave` stuff also from my local `.m2/repository` - just to test - and tried again and now the latest is found.

I guess that the local Maven indexes updated at the same time or the Maven site updated. At first try i got version `4.1.1` as the latest.

In future i guess it is best to update/rebuild maven repo indexes first.